# Font Awesome not displaying when using content

Tags: css, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I have font awesome CSS in my head. If i do this, it works fine:

```
<p>This works</p>
<i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
```

But if I do this I just get the square:

```
<div class="myfaplus"></div>
```

```
.myfaplus:before {
    content: "\f067";
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
}
```

I just dont get it. I pulled apart the font awesome css file and its the exact same?

See https://codepen.io/monstamash/pen/VwvjjWq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `font-weight: 900;` (which is added by the `fas` class)